# Java eclipse - Active directory, attribute modification

Tags: java, eclipse, attributes, active-directory

I want to get attribute on my active directory with Java (Eclipse).

I found this code :

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

// Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, 
        "cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");

// Create the initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

but I have start with this to know if there is a connection:

```
String ldapUrl = "ldap://"+serverAddress+":389";
//Prepare the environment with the username and password.
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
DirContext ctx = null;
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, DOMAIN+username);
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

ctx = LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(ldapUrl, env); // To test the connection
```

So how can I create an InitialDirContext  ? 
What should I put in `env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "?????????")` for that works ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you put what you have in the code you found: `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`? And don't call `getLdapCtxInstance` directly, just do like your example and `new InitialDirContext(env)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you found, the connection is established when you do:

```
// Create the initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

For this to work, you need to have all the required environment properties set, like

```
SECURITY_CREDENTIALS
SECURITY_PRINCIPAL
SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION
PROVIDER_URL
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY
(possibly others depending on if you have encryption set in your Active Directory)
```

The context factory is what Java is going to use to create that connection. If you don't specify it, java will use the default which is `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`, if I'm not mistaken.